# How to stop consent in an Azure multiple tenant application

Tags: authentication, azure, active-directory

I have a multiple tenant application in Azure. Visitors to my site (when trying to log in) are presented with a consent form asking permission to allow the application access to their AD, after which the visitor is then logged in.

How do i stop that happening automatically (and still have multiple tenant)? I would prefer to have some control over who can use our application but still get the benefits of multiple tenancy.

Ideally what i would like is for the user to have to on board by providing some details, and then once we have validated them as a valid user, perhaps provide them with a key which they can enter which then progresses them to the consent screen etc.

So really what i am asking is how do i control access to my application in a multiple tenancy environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one approach you can take:

Have your users sign up for on your website. After they sign up, assign them a unique id (could be a guid or anything else) which will identify them in your database. Then give them an option of signing up for your multi-tenant application by redirecting them to their Azure AD. When you send them to their Azure AD, pass this unique user id as user state. This will be returned back to you after they successfully sign up. When they come back to your website, you can check if this unique id exists in your database or not. If it exists, then grant them access to your application otherwise deny it.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping i could get away with not allowing the user to see the grant screen but i guess thats not possible. After reading your answer and then going back to the samples on GitHub i will block unauthorized users by throwing SecurityTokenValidationException from SecurityTokenValidated event which will give the desired result